# Can PM2 run command line start scripts?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm using a library, say I want the script that starts my app to be `cli-lib start` how can i go about that? I don't want to just run `node app.js` or any js file for that matter, the cli lib does that for me but i cant figure out a way to get this to work.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can run any process type with pm2.
For scripts in other languages which has assigned an interpreter by default,

```
pm2 start echo.coffee
pm2 start echo.php
pm2 start echo.py
pm2 start echo.sh
pm2 start echo.rb
```

or with interpreter

```sh
pm2 start echo.pl --interpreter=perl
```

[read more](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/#start-any-process-type) from docs

Answer (score 6):

I think you can create a bash script then run it with pm2, for examples:

**bash.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
node /home/user/test.js
```

then you can run file "bash.sh" with pm2

```
pm2 start bash.sh
```

I did not test it yet but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use & operate pm2 related command with script in Linux.

- create script file for run.

```
$ sudo nano runpm2.sh
```

- add your relevant command for run pm2. Also you can visit for more command on this [site](https://devhints.io/pm2)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
pm2 restart "a"
pm2 restart "b"
pm2 restart "c"

pm2 start "app.js"

pm2 restart "app_name"
pm2 reload "app_name"
pm2 stop "app_name"
pm2 delete "app_name"
```

- Assign access for run script.

```
sudo chmod +x runpm2.sh
```

- run .sh file with this command.

```
sudo ./runpm2.sh
```